# How can I see the progress of these 3 badges?

Tags: support, badges

How can I see the progress of these 3 badges?

- Announcer;
- Booster;
- Publicist

[image: a picture showing the badges and their descriptions]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As JNat says, there are some badges that aren't trackable:

```
Favorite Question   Question favorited by 25 users
Stellar Question    Question favorited by 100 users 

Popular Question    Question with 1,000 views
Notable Question    Question with 2,500 views
Famous Question     Question with 10,000 views 

Tumbleweed          Asked a question with [...] low views for a week 

Pundit              Leave 10 comments with score of 5 or more 

Precognitive        Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site [...]
Beta                [...] during the private beta 

Constable           Served as a pro-tem moderator [...]
Sheriff             Served as an elected moderator for at least 1 year 

Taxonomist          Create a tag used by 50 questions 

[etc.]
```

Probably the reasoning behind these badges being not trackable is

1. you can't really do anything to get them, and/or
2. progress towards the badge doesn't depend on a single number, but on a number (of views/favourites/upvotes/etc.) for every question/answer of yours.

Answer (score 7):

Just confirmed with a dev, and there's no way to track these :\